# Teltonika FM1100 data parser

Tags: java, python, sockets, gps

I am building TCP/IP socket server in python for teltonika fm1100 device, but I can't parse data. It is not readable. In OpenGTS writen in Java they use class Payload to parse data. Here is what I receive from tracker.

`26E�F��`�@�E�
                     B.�6E�\p����E�
                                           B.�6E�5`�����E�
                                                                  B.�6EP����E�
                                                                                      B.�6E��@� ���E�
                                                                                                             B.�6E��0����E�
                                                                                                                                    B.�6E�� �����E�
                                                                                                                                                           B.�6E�r�����E�
                                                                                                                                                                                  B.�6E�K����E�
                                                                                                                                                                                                        B.�6E�#�� ���E�
                 B.�6E������E�
                                       B.�6E��8��� �E�
                                                              B.�6E�������E�
                                                                                     B.�6E��x�����E�
                                                                                                            B.�6Eߟh���`�E�
                                                                                                                                  B.�6E�xX��`�E�
                                                                                                                                                         B.�6E�QH�0�`E�
                                                                                                                                                                               B.�6E�*8�P��E�
                                                                                                                                                                                                     B.�6E��`��E�
            B.�6E��`�P���E�
                                   B.�6E�����@�E�
                                                         B.�6E����0� E�
                                                                               B.�6E�@�P��E�
                                                                                                     B.�6E��0�0���E�
                                                                                                                            B.�6E�� �0���E�
                                                                                                                                                   B.�6Eۜ�0���E�
                                                                                                                                                                        B.�6E�u�0���E�
                                                                                                                                                                                              B.�6E�M��0�`E�
      B.�6E�&�� �`E�
                            B.�6E����0�`E�
                                                  B.�6E����P�`�E�
                                                                         B.�6Eڱ��p�`E�
                                                                                              B.�6Eڊ����`E�
                                                                                                                   B.�6E�_����`E�
B.�6E�uH�P� E�
                      B.�6E؊������
E�
      B.�6E�c������E�
                             B.�6E�<��`��E�
                                                   B.�6E���P� E�
B.�6E������ E�
B.�6E�ǘ��� E�
B.�6Eנ���� E�
B.�6E�yx��� E�
B.�6E�Rh���E�
                     B.�6E֢��`��E�
                                         B.�6Eո@�0�E�
                                                             B.�6E����`��E�
                                                                                   B.�6E����@�@E�
                                                                                                         B.�6E�� ���`�E�
                                                                                                                                B.�6E����@E�
                                                                                                                                                    B.�2`

Any idea how to read this or how to decode it python

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest starting with the OpenGTS source code.  Since it is hosted on SourceForge, I assume that the source is available.  You should be able to figure out the byte stream format from their message parser.  Once you know the data format, use something like the [`struct` module](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) to parse the binary and write a few classes to represent the data in a nice Pythonic way.

Comment: I am not familiar with Java. so it will be great if someone tell me byte stream format